# Issue with item order in List and CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 CheckedListBox that contains 3 strings each:

CheckedListBox1: "Apricot", "Banana", "Cherry"
CheckedListBox2: "Apple", "Blueberry", "Clementine"

I would like that everytime I click on my Button1, it checks if it contains the item, and if not it adds it to myList1 for CheckedListBox1, and myList2 for CheckedListBox2, but in the same order. I mean:

1. I check Apricot and Cherry, so myList1 is: "Apricot", "Cherry"
2. I uncheck them and check only Banana, so the list is: "Apricot", "Cherry", "Banana"

So I want the Apricot always being first, Banana second and Cherry third.
Same for myList2, obviously.

My actual code is:

```
Dim myList1 As New List(Of String)
Dim myList2 As New List(Of String)
Dim myFullList As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Submit() Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        If Not myList1.Contains(item) Then
            myList1.Add(item)
        End If
    Next

    For Each item In CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems
        If Not myList2.Contains(item) Then
            myList2.Add(item)
        End If
    Next

    myFullList.Add(String.Join(", ", myList1)
    myFullList.Add(String.Join(", ", myList2)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, guys ! :)

Comment: So, to be clear, you want `myList1` to contain the checked items from `CheckListBox1` and in the same order as they appear in the control? If so, why not simply get those items from the control as and when you need them, i.e. `CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of String)().ToList()`?

Comment: Yes, I want ```myList1``` to contain the checked items from ```CheckedListBox1``` but I also want ```myList1``` to KEEP the items that were checked once, even if they are unchecked now. And still in the same order, of course.

Comment: `myList1.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Well this one is kind of what I'm looking for, the problem is that my strings are not necessarily in alphabetic order. For example, Banana is index 0, Cherry is index 1 and Apricot is index 2.

But yes, that's the ```List.Sort``` method that I'm probably looking for, then I need to sort by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider doing things a bit differently. Define a custom type and bind a list of that type to the `CheckedListBox`. When an item is checked, set a flag in that item. You can then just get the items from that list that have that flag set.

```vb
Public Class CheckListItem

    Public Property Text As String

    Public Property Checked As Boolean

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function

End Class
```

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim items = {New CheckListItem With {.Text = "Apricot"},
                 New CheckListItem With {.Text = "Banana"},
                 New CheckListItem With {.Text = "Cherry"}}

    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = items
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index), CheckListItem).Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim checkedItems = CheckedListBox1.Items.Cast(Of CheckListItem)().Where(Function(cli) cli.Checked)

    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", checkedItems))
End Sub
```

Comment: So I have an exception thrown:

```System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.RefreshItems()```

Comment: I tested the exact code I posted here and it worked for me so you're going to have to be more specific about exactly what you did and exactly what happened and when. There may be something I didn't take into account but I can't fix it if I don't know how to reproduce it.